# Codeigniter ошибка в модели

Tags: php, codeigniter

Model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class user_model extends CI_Model {
    public function getUser()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get("users");
        $data = $query->result();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class main extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->home();
        $this->user();
    }
    public function home() {
        // Информация на главной
        $data['title'] = "Мой блог";
        // Обработчик вывода объектов
        $this->load->model('items_model');
        $data['items'] = $this->items_model->getItem(); 
        $this->load->view('main',$data);
    }
    public function user() {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $data['user'] = $this->users_model->getUser(); 
        $this->load->view('main',$data);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?=$title;?>
                <?php foreach($items as $row): ?>
                <!--start-->
                <div class="item-block">
                    <div class="item-block-over">
                        <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $row->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->title; ?>"></a>
                        <div class="item-block-bottom">
                            <a href=""><?php echo $row->title; ?></a>
                            <span>$<?php echo $row->price; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end-->
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <span><?php echo $user['id']; ?></span>
```

выдает ошибку

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: main::$users_model

Filename: controllers/main.php

Line Number: 22

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\main.php
Line: 22
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\main.php
Line: 8
Function: user

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once


Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\main.php on line 22
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function getUser() on null

Filename: controllers/main.php

Line Number: 22

Backtrace:
```

Answer (score 2):

1) ошибки тут

```
class user_model extends CI_Model
```

должно быть

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
```

2) еще

```
$data = $query->result();
```

сделайте

```
$data = $query->result_array();
```

3) и в контроллоре

```
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $data['user'] = $this->users_model->getUser();
```

должно быть

```
   $this->load->model('user_model');
   $data['user'] = $this->user_model->getUser();
```

4) в view

```
<span><?php echo $user['id']; ?></span>
```

подправить как

```
<span><?php echo (isset($user) && isset($user['id'])) ? $user['id'] : ''; ?></span>
```

Comment: Теперь выдает A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: user
Filename: views/main.php
Line Number: 54
Backtrace:
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\main.php
Line: 54
Function: _error_handler
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\main.php
Line: 18
Function: view
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\main.php
Line: 7
Function: home
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: это тут <span><?php echo $user['id']; ?></span> проверьте есть ли в переменной $user данные

Comment: Данных нету, модель выглядит вот так 
 public function getUser()
 {
  $query = $this->db->get("users");
  $data = $query->result();
  return $data;
 } контроллер вот так 
 public function user() {
  $this->load->model('user_model');
  $data['user'] = $this->user_model->getUser(); 
  $this->load->view('main',$data);
 } суть в том, что $data тоже почему то не выводит данные

Comment: у вас нету данных в таблице `users`

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#26 (5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(12) "Дима" ["password"]=> string(32) "20f1f5ed4d05d0b0a4f6fe4b28110465" ["email"]=> string(14) "admin@site.com" ["favorites"]=> string(1) "0" } }
Записи есть)

Comment: Ошибка по прежнему осталась)

Comment: вы работаете с объектами если `query->result()` если хотите как массив используйте `query->result_array()` я указал в ответе (2)

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29138/discussion-between--and-saidolim-djuraev).